# Need help converting sql query into laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I need the following sql query into laravel query or how can I run into laravel as it is. thanks

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (SELECT client_id,product_name, max(real_date) AS max_date
        FROM api_hilbertis.transactions
        WHERE active = 1 AND real_date <= '2019-03-01'
        GROUP BY client_id, product_name) AS m

INNER JOIN api_hilbertis.transactions AS t
        ON t.client_id = m.client_id
        AND t.product_name = m.product_name
        AND t.real_date = m.max_date
        AND active = 1
ORDER BY real_date DESC;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel raw queries.
Example [HERE](https://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries)

So for your case it we could write something like:

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (SELECT client_id,product_name, max(real_date) AS max_date
        FROM api_hilbertis.transactions
        WHERE active = 1 AND real_date <= '2019-03-01'
        GROUP BY client_id, product_name) AS m

INNER JOIN api_hilbertis.transactions AS t
        ON t.client_id = m.client_id
        AND t.product_name = m.product_name
        AND t.real_date = m.max_date
        AND active = 1
ORDER BY real_date DESC"
 ));
```

EDIT: example with variables:

```
$someVariable = $request->input('some_variable');

$results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_col = :somevariable"), 
['somevariable' => $someVariable,]
);
```

Comment: Thank you Djokic. Do you in the query can I insert variable as a part of the query? for example in the real_date can I put laravel variable {{ date }} ? code will be like this,

Comment: ``$results = DB::select( DB::raw("
``SELECT  t.*
``FROM    (SELECT client_id,product_name, max(real_date) AS max_date
  ``      FROM api_hilbertis.transactions
``        WHERE active = 1 AND real_date <= {{date}}
``        GROUP BY client_id, product_name) AS m
``
``INNER JOIN api_hilbertis.transactions AS t
``        ON t.client_id = m.client_id
``        AND t.product_name = m.product_name
``        AND t.real_date = m.max_date
``        AND active = 1
``ORDER BY real_date DESC"
`` ));

Comment: Hey @SarderIftekhar. I edited my answer with example of how to pass variable to a query.